# the prices I fetched with binance API are not correct

Tags: python, python-3.x, binance, python-binance

I'm fetching the prices for arbitrage but some of the prices seem correct, some are incorrect. i tried more than 20 ways but cant fix it.

```
last_data = [["ETHBTC", "BTCPAX", "PAXETH"],["ETHBTC", "BTCTUSD", "TUSDETH"],... ...]
for a in last_data:
  az = 1.0
  for y in a:
    response = requests.get(f"https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol={y}")
    az *= float(response.json()["price"])
    print(y)
  print(az)
```

**output:**

```
ETHBTC
BTCPAX
PAXETH
23.520797834005702

ETHBTC
BTCTUSD
TUSDETH
16.47345165311804
```

---

Numbers that should normally be:

```
first avg: 0,909
second avg: 0,929
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the 3 numbers you extract right now? Multiply them together? And could you please provide the API outputs for each symbol? Binance is unavailable in the US

Comment: The first three prices are `0.05153, 51529.15, 0.00888047`. How you can get the value `0,909` from these three values?

Comment: {"symbol":"ETHBTC","price":"0.05143000"}
{"symbol":"BTCPAX","price":"51529.15000000"}
{"symbol":"PAXETH","price":"0.00888047"}

but true prices are 
ETHBTC = 0,05
BTCPAX = 20.9
PAXETH = 0.84
I need to multiply these three numbers and get a value.
@DanielCentore

Comment: No, the BTCPAX rate is not 20.9.  It's currently 40101.  Where are you getting 20.9 from?

Comment: coingecko,coinbase,kraken,binance all the same 1 btc equals = 20 pax